# Отправка кастомного уведомления покупателю Wordpress/Woocommerce о покупке

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, уведомления

На сайте всего четыре товара.
Письмо покупателю отправляется после оплаты. Здесь никаких проблем.
Как сделать, чтобы при покупке разных товаров в зависимости от ID товара, а не от статуса заказа, отправлялись бы разные письма?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы нашел.
В принципе в инете есть рекомендации по созданию собственного плагина для этих нужд, но есть и готовый плагин.
Его нет в Wordpress, но его можно скачать с GitHub: https://github.com/alexmustin/woocustomemails
Я попробовал - мне понравилось.
Кому нужно - рекомендую.
Нужно будет только отредактировать штатные письма Woocommerce, если нужно убрать лишнее.
И еще можно посмотреть маленький ролик на Youtube с пояснениями: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2qJf1v0UqM&t=72s